# How to extract multipart attachments from SOAP response

Tags: c#, soap, multipart

I am trying to extract the multipart attachment portion of a SOAP response.

I have a project that uses a Web Reference to talk to a 3rd party web service. I'm able to successfully make requests and get valid responses back from the service, but I don't understand where if anywhere the attachment data is going. Looking through the Web Reference autogenerated code there aren't any objects that match up to the actual attachment data.

Are there any kind options that I need to set when originally consuming the 3rd party WSDL to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had hoped there would be a .NET multipart boundary parser already, but wasn't able to find one so I wrote my own.

I have done this by getting the raw HTTP response as a string, splitting on the part boundaries `------=_Part_*`. Then for each part looking for `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`, and then extracting the base 64 region and using `Convert.FromBase64String` to convert that to a byte array, and finally saving that as a file.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely sounds like the way to go. I'm not super familiar with .Net though, will I be able to get access to the raw HTTP response if I override the GetWebResponse method?

Comment: Some of these examples might be helpful to get you on the right track http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/Web-Request-Response.htm